# Populate Flow variable with Parent Id - from VisualForce page - launched by related list Custom Button

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, visual-workflow, related-list, list-button

I have created a Flow which allows my users to insert multiple `Currency_Detail__c` records from one page.

The Currency Detail records have a Master-Detail relationship with Opportunities. I have created a variable in the Flow `OppId` which, as the name suggests, will store the Id of the Opportunity which each Currency Detail record needs to be related to.

I now need to add a custom button to the Currency Detail related records list, to launch the Flow and to populate the `OppId` variable, with the Id of the Opportunity which the user is viewing.

I've created this VisualForce page

```
<apex:page standardController="Currency_Detail__c" recordSetVar="Currency_Details">
   <flow:interview name="Create_Currency_Detail_Records" finishLocation="/{!Id}"/>
   <apex:param name="OppId" value="{!Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I use this, it causes an error

> (REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING) Required fields are missing: [Opportunity__c] --- for SFDC record with ID : null

so it looks like the variable's not being populated.

This is probably completely off the mark but I can't save the page if I change `value="{!Id}"` to `value="{!Opportunity.Id}"`

> Unknown property 'Currency_Detail__cStandardController.Opportunity'

How can I populate the Flow's `OppId` variable from the VisualForce page?

**UPDATE**

Just to make sure that the setup of my Flow's not the cause of the issue, this is how the Record Create elements are configured

[image: Record Create Screen]

The other two fields are taking their values from screen input fields on a screen element earlier in the Flow.

The `OppId` variable is set to Input & Output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make the Custom Button as an onclick javascript button and then open the VF Page by passing the opportunity id as a parameter to the page (say call id oppId) and then pass that parameter to the flow..

so your Custom Button properties will be

- Display Type - List Button
- Behaviour - Execute Javascript
- Content Source - Onclick Javascript

and then in the script section point it to your VF page with the param

```javascript
window.location = '/apex/YourVFPage?oppId={!Opportunity.Id}'
```

then in your VF page you can do

**UPDATE :**

the param tag was outside the flow tag which is why the value was not getting passed into the flow.. please use the correct syntax as below

```
<apex:page standardController="Currency_Detail__c" recordSetVar="Currency_Details">
   <flow:interview name="Create_Currency_Detail_Records" finishLocation="/{!Id}">
       <apex:param name="OppId" value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.oppId}"/>
   </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks Vamsi but I get 'unexpected token ILLEGAL' when I click the button, having made those changes.

Comment: i jus gave a rough idea on the redirection. you have to use window.location assignment syntax.. just updated the code.

Comment: That's fixed the 'ILLEGAL' error but I'm still getting the first 'required fields are missing' error

Comment: can u share your flow details where you are creating the currency detail records and relating them to opportunity id passed in the variable ?

Comment: and did u mark the oppId variable in the flow as input variable ?

Comment: It's Input & Output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26011/discussion-between-vamsi-krishna-and-alex-s).